# Cannot access FastAPI app behind Apache HTTPS proxy on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, apache2, fastapi, reverse-proxy

**I'm struggling to serve my FastAPI app securely on forge-code.com with HTTPS.**

**Here's what I've done so far:**

Deployed my FastAPI app on a Google Cloud instance.
Successfully accessed the app using HTTPS directly through the instance's IP address.
Purchased a domain forge-code.com on Hostinger and configured it to forward requests to my instance.
Installed an SSL certificate from Certbot and accessed the Apache2 index.html file on my instance via https://forge-code.com.
My problem: When I access https://forge-code.com, I see the Apache2 index.html instead of my FastAPI app.
My 000-default.conf file looks like this:

```
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                                                     000-default.conf                                                                                                              
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forge-code.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =forge-code.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

00-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
        SSLEngine on
        ServerName forge-code.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forge-code.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forge-code.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Here is some more information
These are the output of

`systemctl status apache2`

```
shivajay295@instance-20240221-193932:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-02-23 18:37:43 UTC; 2h 30min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 46449 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 47594 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 46455 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 1141)
     Memory: 12.5M
        CPU: 1.008s
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─46455 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─47598 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─47599 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Feb 23 18:37:43 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 23 18:37:43 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Started apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 23 20:56:01 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Reloading apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 23 20:56:01 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Reloaded apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 23 21:02:15 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Reloading apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 23 21:02:15 instance-20240221-193932 systemd[1]: Reloaded apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.
shivajay295@instance-20240221-193932:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

`sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S`

```
shivajay295@instance-20240221-193932:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  forge-code.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   forge-code.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
shivajay295@instance-20240221-193932:/etc/apache2/sites-available$
```

**Additional information:**

I'm using Ubuntu on my Google Cloud instance.
I've verified that I have read permissions for the SSL certificate and key files.
I'm unsure why my FastAPI app isn't being served through forge-code.com.
What do I need to do to successfully serve my FastAPI app with HTTPS on forge-code.com?

Comment: Did you reload or restart Apache after changing the virtual host? Your configuration has no entries to serve the default Apache index file.

Comment: @JohnHanley I reloaded multiple times. Still not working. sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: What does `systemctl status apache2` show? Also `apache2ctl -S`. Edit your question and show those commands and results.

Comment: @JohnHanley Edits made

Comment: You have five virtual hosts enabled. Disable all virtual hosts. Then configure one virtual host configuration file for port 80 and another for port 443 plus the SSL configuration. You have 443 configured in `000-default.conf` which should be located in `000-default-le-ssl.conf`. Once you complete that, update your question and include both conf files and update the command outputs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have made the edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a FastAPI App on a Domain with Apache and SSL:

**1. Domain Purchase and DNS Configuration:**

Acquire a domain: Purchase a domain name (e.g., forge-code.com) from a reputable domain registrar.
Point DNS records: In your domain's DNS settings, create an A record that maps your domain to the IP address of your GCP instance:

```
Type: A

Name: @ (or leave blank)

Value: 34.131.190.233 (replace with your instance's IP)

TTL: 14400 (or a suitable value)
```

**2. SSL Certificate Installation:**

Obtain a certificate: Use Certbot to obtain a free SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt:

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache
sudo certbot --apache -d forge-code.com
```

**3. Apache Configuration:**

Edit virtual hosts: Modify the following files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

**000-default-le-ssl.conf (for HTTPS):**
Ensure SSLEngine is enabled.

Set ServerName to your domain.

Include SSL certificate and key files.

ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to your FastAPI app's port (8000).

Here is my conf file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
        SSLEngine on
        ServerName forge-code.com
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forge-code.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/forge-code.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

**000-default.conf (for HTTP):**
Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS using a RewriteRule.

Here is my conf file

```
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                                                000-default.conf                                                                                                          
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forge-code.com

    # Enable proxy modules
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/

    # Rewrite rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =forge-code.com
    SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**4. Apache Restart:**

Reload configuration:
`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

**5. FastAPI App Startup:**

Run FastAPI app:
`venv/bin/uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

**Additional Considerations:**

**Firewall rules:** Ensure your firewall allows traffic on ports 80 and 443.

**FastAPI app configuration:** Verify that your FastAPI app is configured to listen on port 8000.

**Troubleshooting:** Use Apache logs (/var/log/apache2/error.log) for troubleshooting any issues.

**Process management:** Consider using a process manager like systemd or supervisord to keep your FastAPI app running in the background.
Alternative proxying: If Apache encounters challenges, explore Nginx or HAProxy as alternative proxy solutions.

**Key Points:**

**Domain configuration:** Accurate DNS settings are crucial for directing traffic to your server.

**SSL certificates:** Secure communication with HTTPS requires valid SSL certificates.

**Apache configuration:** Proper configuration enables Apache to proxy requests to your FastAPI app and handle SSL.

**FastAPI app startup:** Ensure your app is running and listening on the correct port.

**Troubleshooting:** Log files and process management are essential for identifying and resolving issues.

And Bingo here your fastapi app is running on your domain!!!